# How to remove all the non parent-child links in a Directed Acyclic Graph?

Tags: algorithms, cart

I have some Directed Acyclic Graph trees representing biological features.
In my database, I can retrieve all the links between every child and its ancestors: I have all the edges and the nodes.

Unfortunately, I have not only the direct links between every child and its parent, but I have also the indirect links between the child and the ancestors.
I want to remove all these links between children and ancestors.

You can see an example in the following picture:

[image]
From my link list, I want to remove LS1S4 and LS1S3 and LS1S5 (the red ones), and mantain LS1S2, LS1S3, LS1S4 (the black ones).

I need an algorithm to do this, I've tried to design many of them but I always failed something...

Here are the input data:

- nodes: S1, S2, S3, S4, S5.
- links: LS1S4, LS1S3, LS1S5, LS1S2, LS1S3, LS1S4.

How to understand which are the red links and which the black links?

Thanks

Comment: hi Davide, I'm curious to know whether you got anywhere with the solution I posted?

Comment: Hi Tootone. Your solution was correct but I found another algorithm workin' better. The key principle was that node N is direct child of node A if A has no child that is parent of N. Thanks anyway

Comment: cool, out of interest, what's the algorithm?

Comment: In mathematics, this operation is called Transitive Reduction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction

Answer (score 1):

Allocate each node a label of 1. Then perform a search (breadth-first / depth-first / doesn't matter), using a set `S` of nodes to visit. Start with `S = { root }`.

1. If the set `S` is empty, finish.
2. Remove a node `N` from `S`.
3. Let `n` be the current label of `N`, and `w = n + 1`.
4. For each downstream node `d` with a `label < w`, set its `label = w`, and add `d` to `S`.

As a result of this, the the difference between labels on any two nodes should reflect the *maximum* distance between those nodes. The last step ensures that any shortcut taken by traversing a transitive link is overwritten by the longer distance determined by stepping through the tree structure.

In a second pass, remove all edges which connect nodes whose labels differ by more than 1.

---

In your example

- Set labels `L = { S1=1, S2=1, S3=1, S4=1, S5=1 }`, and `S = { S1 }`.
- Remove `S1` from `S`, `n=1`, `w=2`. The nodes `S2, S3, S4, S5` are downstream from `S1` with labels < 2 and so have their labels reset and are added to `S`. Hence `L = { S1=1, S2=2, S3=2, S4=2, S5=2 }`, and `S = { S2, S3, S4, S5 }`.
- Remove `S3`, say, from `S`, `n=2`, `w=3`. The node `S5` is downstream from `S3` with label < 3, so has its label reset and added to `S`. Hence `L = { S1=1, S2=2, S3=2, S4=2, S5=3 }`, and `S = { S2, S4, S5 }`.
- Remove S2, say, from `S`, `n=2`, `w=3.` The nodes `S3, S4` are downstream from `S2` with label < 3, so have their labels reset and are added to `S`. Hence `L = { S1=1, S2=2, S3=3, S4=3, S5=3 }`, and `S = { S3, S4, S5 }`.
- Remove `S4`, say, from `S`, `n=3`, `w=4`. There are no nodes downstream from `S4`, and nothing to do. Hence `L = { S1=1, S2=2, S3=3, S4=3, S5=3 }`, and `S = { S3, S5 }`.
- Remove `S3`, say, from `S`, `n=3`, `w=4`. The node `S5` is downstream from `S3` with label < 4, so has its label reset and is added to `S`. Hence `L = { S1=1, S2=2, S3=3, S4=3, S5=4 }`, and `S = { S5 }`.
- Remove `S5` from `S`, `n=4`, `w=5`. There are no nodes downstream from `S4`, and nothing to do. Hence `L = { S1=1, S2=2, S3=3, S4=3, S5=4 }`, and `S = { }`, the empty set, and we terminate.

In the second pass, we remove `LS1S5`, `LS1S3`, `LS1S4` because  the difference in the labels of `S1` and `S5` is 3 > 1, and the difference in the labels of `S1` and `S3` is 2 > 1, and the difference in the labels of `S1` and `S4` is 2 > 1.